# How can I have Android on the RasPi with Accel/Gyro?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, accelerometer, gyroscope

For a project, I want to use a Raspberry Pi (or similar) running Android. Just using a mobile device is not an option (due to ruggedness, always-on, breakout-options etc.)

The other thing my project needs is sensor input from an accelerometer/gyroscope, providing my "RasPi installed Android" with readings for orientation, in pitch and roll (I don't need azimuth).

On a native smartphone, accel/gyro are always hardware-based [ref 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion) [ref 2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor) and just work (via i2c). Now RasPi doesn't have those sensors. Also, I don't know if Android would detect those automagically if it would.

How can I add an accel/gyro sensor to RasPi (or similar) that would be detected and be naturally read out just like with a smartphone running Android?

I know I can add a third-party USB accel/gyro, but these usually stream CSV data and would be a separate data stream from the "native" accel/gyro Android input, right? Any options to have data be fed into the native Android orientation sensor sink?

Comment: See: https://source.android.com/docs/core/interaction/sensors and a bit of research shows that a AOSP fork of Android exists for RaspberryPi4 https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/AOSP13/ that appears to support `Sensors (using external GPIO I2C modules e.g. MPU6050, LSM6DS3, LSM303DLHC, BME280/BMP280, and APDS9930 accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, temperature, pressure, humidity, ambient light, and proximity)`

Comment: That's valuable info. Thanks!
Anyone here already been there and can give me pointers on how to connect one of those IMU boards via i2c and have Android recognize them?